# Javafx AnchorPane in Maxsized screen always placed top left side

Tags: javafx, alignment, fxml, scenebuilder

i use scene builder to build a gui for my app and i have this problem:
When stage screen is set to Maximized , AnchorPane is set top left corner and all it's contents inside(VBox etc). i want to cover the full screen or at least be at the center. Im not too familiar with anchorPane alignment and positioning but wit borderpane i didn't have that problem. So here is how my screen looks : [image]
So the anchorpane just is being placed always top left like this.

Here is my fxml code:

```
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="394.0" prefWidth="586.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gr.hua.dit.oop2.gui.Controller2">
       <children>
          <VBox layoutY="29.0" prefHeight="116.0" prefWidth="344.0" spacing="30.0">
             <children>
                <TextField fx:id="name" alignment="TOP_CENTER" promptText="Enter your full name" />
                <TextField fx:id="age" alignment="BASELINE_CENTER" promptText="Enter your age" />
             </children>
          </VBox>
          <VBox layoutX="425.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="161.0" spacing="10.0">
             <children>
                <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" text="Tell us your interests" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="museum" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="36.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Museums" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="sights" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Historical Sights" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="night" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="88.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Night Life" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="forest" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="114.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Forests" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="lake" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Lakes" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="zoo" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Zoo" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="sea" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="218.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sea - Beach" />
                <CheckBox fx:id="mountain" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="254.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Mountains" />
             </children>
          </VBox>
          <Button fx:id="submit" alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" layoutX="269.0" layoutY="360.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Proposal">
             <font>
                <Font size="15.0" />
             </font>
          </Button>
          <VBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="174.0" prefHeight="161.0" prefWidth="375.0">
             <children>
                <TextField fx:id="cities" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="334.0" promptText="Enter up to 5 Desired Cities you want to Visit">
                   <font>
                      <Font size="10.0" />
                   </font>
                </TextField>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="TOP" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="377.0" text="e.g. &quot;Athens gr,Berlin de,New York us" />
             </children>
          </VBox>
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: What do you expect? You are hard-coding all the layout coordinates and preferred sizes. If you want your UI to be responsive, use a layout pane that lays things out the way you want (probably not an `AnchorPane`), and let the layout pane manage the size and position of the child nodes, instead of setting their values.

Comment: i made the fxml using the scene builder, i didn't edit the fxml. Maybe the values were added automatically. Ok undestand what you say, but i don't get the purpose  of anchorPane then. I mean it should have an option to align it or position it whatever

Comment: Different layout panes lay their child nodes out in different ways. The anchor pane layout clearly isn’t what you need here. All the properties that are set can be set from Scene Builder.

Comment: ok i will use something different, but i was curious about anchorpane. Thanks for the responses i truly appreciate it